# multisite not working: one site correctly redirected, the other one throwing 500 error

Tags: multi-sites

Using  `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` and Drupal 7.

Installed Drupal on `/var/www/html/drupal`

Created folders

```
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/siteone.org.es
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/sitetwo.com
```

Added settings.php inside the folders above

Modified `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to include

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
ServerName sitetwo.com
SeverAlias *.sitetwo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
ServerName siteone.org.es
SeverAlias *.siteone.org.es
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to Firefox and navigate to `sitetwo.com` it works fine and the Drupal site is loaded without issues. However, when I navigate to `siteone.org.es` I get a 500 error. These are the details from Firefox:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Service unavailable (with message)
Date: Sun, 28 Aug 2022 09:58:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: es
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Permissions-Policy: interest-cohort=()
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

any clue what am I missing?

Comment: 500 errors are logged. Examine logs for more information.

Comment: where are they logged? there's nothing about 500 errors on `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: There is an older article at https://www.drupal.org/node/158043 covering this. System logging levels and locations and PHP error reporting  are particular to how you set up the platform.

Comment: How does your sites.php file look like?

Answer (score -4):

I figured out what the the issue was by visiting /update.php on the site and reading the detailed error message. Several not installed modules were the main reason, among others.